# How to better implement Like/Unlike System using mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, wordpress

I am developing a like/unlike system for my Wordpress Multisite using jquery, php and mysql. Basically, sub-sites have posts and products where user can like and unlike them. My plan is to store the likes in a global table so I can use it also for the main site to display the posts and the number of likes and have a separate page for the Most Liked Posts/products and some sort.

In my mysql table naming `global_likes` I have these columns.

`like_id | user_id | blog_id | object_id | object_type | date_added`

Example Datas would be:

```
like_id | user_id | blog_id | object_id | object_type | date_added

1       | 24      | 81      | 403       | post        | 2014-01-22 05:55:23

2       | 36      | 29      | 108       | product     | 2013-02-26 12:23:10
```

In my jquery I use this as part:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/wp-content/plugins/plugname/like.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        object_id: object_id,
        user_id: user_id,
        type: 'like',
        blog_id: blog_id,
        object_type: object_type,
        count: default_count
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        var new_count = parseInt(default_count) + 1;
        jQuery('#like_click_' + object_id).attr('data-like-count', new_count);              
        jQuery('#like_click_' + object_id).attr('id', '#unlike_click_' + object_id);
        isProcessing = false;
    }
});
```

In my server side PHP I use this as part which inserts the datas after some sort of validation:

```
$wpdb->insert( 
$global_likes, 
array( 
    'user_id' => $user_id, 
    'blog_id' => $blog_id, 
    'object_id' => $object_id, 
    'object_type' => $object_type,
    'date_added' => $date_added
)
);
```

Thats it. Now, the problem is it is expected to have many rows as likes get inserted by different users on different posts/products from different blogs. Its like thousands or millions just like that.

Is that a overkill?? or may cause heavy load as I use currently 512mb application RAM. I'm greatly concerned with the performance and CPU usage. Considering that the likes are obtained on each posts/products from different blogs and at the same time, it is displayed also on the main site which displays all the posts from across the blogs along with the number of likes. Also, users can also like/unlike a post from the main site.

Example is:
When displaying a post or product either on a specific blog or in main site,

- The number of likes is being queried and displayed.
- Check if user has or has not liked the post by checking the `user_id`
  on the global table.
- User can unlike/like the post or product.

On main site also in User profile page.

- The global likes table is being queried to check for the user's liked items and displayed.
- The number of liked items from across the network.

Am I using the correct and better way to implement this OR is there a more better way. I only know php, jquery and mysql. If you're thinking of like `nosql` or same like that, It might not help me since I'm using wordpress and I don't know how to us it at all.

Comment: Main concern in relation to databases is whether they're properly indexed and if you're properly selecting indexed values instead of, for example, select * . Using prepared statements does help when it comes to performance. Giving your user an instance of a database connection to work with can safe you from creating new connections every few seconds, but allowing them to live forever can cause problems aswell. Not sure if this question belongs to SO but it's fairly well formatted. Maybe you should read about database optimization but it looks pretty legit. You should try to penetrate-test it.

Comment: How to properly index? how can I use prepared statements?

Comment: Both topics have been covered all over the internet, the first google searches should do the trick. Basically the way you're designing your database is fine; you're using foreign key constraints and look up ids and values corresponding to ids. At least I hope you're using foreign key constraints.